# DAO Contracts Specs for Ink?

Tags: ink

Are there any Ink contract example implementations for DAOs?
A contract that supports Voting using weights for members from a Multisig contract?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check my example inspired by Governor contract of OpenZeppelin:

https://github.com/AstarNetwork/WASM-Governor-Workshop

It supports Vote using weights of a governance token.
For Multisig you can have a look at parity multisig example:
https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/multisig

Comment: the parity link is broken. here is the correct link.
https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/multisig